# How can I specify the order of imports in intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, ide

Intellij keeps reordering my imports like so:

```
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.InternalError;
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.*;
```

Whereas our maven checkstyle wants the order like so:

```
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.*;
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.InternalError;
```

I should also point out, that this doesn't apply to all the imports, only some of them.
I'd like to set it so intellij organises all packages that end with a `*` to be sorted above fully qualified imports on the same path?

So like this:

```
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.*;
import app.v1.myModule.db.model.InternalError;
import app.v1.myModule.service.*;
import app.v1.myModule.service.MyService;
```

For the record, the extra classes are added when the import is ambiguous, so we can't use the `*` for those particular classes.

Here is a screenshot of how my settings currently look:
[image]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot from `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports | Import Layout`. Try to put imports with `*` above others using up/down arrows. E.g. https://prnt.sc/Yi2nnpRfg-2i

Comment: I tired adding as you suggested, but then it reorders other imports too and checkstyle fails again. What I want is for `import my.package.*` to be above `import my.package.class` in every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following layout for imports with `*`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ you can go to settings -> code style -> java -> Imports Tab

There you have the Imports layout, where you can set up your needed settings.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question, it doesn't apply to every import with an `*` only some of them, which is doubly weird.